# Sorting List of Objects based on multiple fields with Special Criteria

Tags: java, sorting, jakarta-ee

I am trying to sort List of objects based on two fields [**Name**, **Old name**] in Ascending Order where **Name** field value can be dash ("-"), And if the name is Dash then it will be added into end of the list. [Like below ordering : Name : Old name]

```
SENSITIVE: COMP Operations: COMP Operations
SENSITIVE: Court procedural documents: Court procedural documents
SENSITIVE: Staff matter: Staff Matter
SPECIAL HANDLING: ETS Critical: ETS Critical
-: ETS Limited
-: EU Satellite Navigation matters
-: Limited ETS Joint Procurement
```

So far I got the below result:

```
-: ETS Limited
-: EU Satellite Navigation matters
-: Limited ETS Joint Procurement
SENSITIVE: COMP Operations: COMP Operations
SENSITIVE: Court procedural documents: Court procedural documents
SENSITIVE: Staff matter: Staff Matter
SPECIAL HANDLING: ETS Critical: ETS Critical
```

The domain model:

```
class Marking {
    String name;
    String oldName;

    public Marking(String name, String oldName) {
        this.name = name;
        this.oldName = oldName;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getOldName() {
        return oldName;
    }

    public void setOldName(String oldName) {
        this.oldName = oldName;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Marking [name=" + name + ", oldName=" + oldName + "]";
    }
}
```

And the Solution Class:

```
public class Solution {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Marking> markings = new ArrayList<>();
        markings.add(new Marking("-", "Limited ETS Joint Procurement"));
        markings.add(new Marking("-", "EU Satellite Navigation matters"));
        markings.add(new Marking("SENSITIVE: Court procedural documents", "Court procedural documents"));
        markings.add(new Marking("SENSITIVE: COMP Operations", "COMP Operations"));
        markings.add(new Marking("-", "ETS Limited"));
        markings.add(new Marking("SENSITIVE: Staff matter", "Staff Matter"));
        markings.add(new Marking("SPECIAL HANDLING: ETS Critical", "ETS Critical"));

        Collections.sort(markings, new Comparator<Marking>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(Marking o1, Marking o2) {
                int value = o1.getName().compareToIgnoreCase(o2.getName());
                if(value == 0) {
                    return o1.getOldName().compareToIgnoreCase(o2.getOldName());
                }
                return value;
            }
        });


        for (Marking marking : markings) {
            System.out.println(marking.getName() + ": " + marking.getOldName());
        }
    }
}
```

Anybody can give me some suggestion, how can I add dash name Object into end of the list where Old name should be order in Ascending order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one option i can think of quickly:

```
  Collections.sort(markings, (o1, o2) -> {

            int value = o1.getName().compareToIgnoreCase(o2.getName());
            if(value == 0) {
                return o1.getOldName().compareToIgnoreCase(o2.getOldName());
            }

            if(o1.getName().equals("-")) {
                return 1;
            }
            if(o2.getName().equals("-")) {
                return -1;
            }

            return value;
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

This is one suggestion. The ordering is **fine**, all we do is take all elements that start with "-" and remove them from the list, then add them back at the end. It's inefficient but it's a resolve.

```java
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Marking> markings = new ArrayList<>();

        markings.add(new Marking("-", "Limited ETS Joint Procurement"));
        markings.add(new Marking("-", "EU Satellite Navigation matters"));
        markings.add(new Marking("SENSITIVE: Court procedural documents", "Court procedural documents"));
        markings.add(new Marking("SENSITIVE: COMP Operations", "COMP Operations"));
        markings.add(new Marking("-", "ETS Limited"));
        markings.add(new Marking("SENSITIVE: Staff matter", "Staff Matter"));
        markings.add(new Marking("SPECIAL HANDLING: ETS Critical", "ETS Critical"));


        markings.sort((o1, o2) -> {
            int value = o1.getName().compareToIgnoreCase(o2.getName());

            if (value == 0) {
                return o1.getOldName().compareToIgnoreCase(o2.getOldName());
            }
            return value;
        });

        List<Marking> dashed = markings.stream().filter(marking -> marking.name.startsWith("-") || marking.oldName.startsWith("-"))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        markings.removeAll(dashed);

        markings.addAll(dashed);

        for (Marking marking : markings) {
            System.out.println(marking.getName() + ": " + marking.getOldName());
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but I am looking the solution into Compare method. Is it possible?

Comment: A user provided a solution below! :)